# Select first child that has proper class

Tags: jquery, css

I want to get first li that has class "menu" (if script will work correct, Link1 should be colored red color).
Here's plunk with my attempts http://plnkr.co/edit/vc6Dz23mXCipw2IjKAJe?p=preview

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".page-sidebar .menu :first").addClass("active"); //???
  $(".page-sidebar .menu :first :first-child").addClass("active");
});
```

Comment: remove the spaces. if you are refering to li with class .menu it should be with no space. if you have space space it will look for child

Answer (score 1):

Just try:

```
$(".page-sidebar .menu:first").addClass("active");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 $(".page-sidebar .menu :first").addClass("active"); //???
```

Become

```
 $(".page-sidebar .menu:first").addClass("active"); //???
```

And that's done.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(".page-sidebar .menu:first").addClass("active"); //???
```

```css
.active{
  color:red
  
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="page-sidebar">
      <li class="toggler"><button class="btn btn-info"></button></li>
      <li class="search"><input type="text" placeholder="Search..."></li>
      <li class="menu">Link1
        <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li>Link1.1</li>
          <li>Link1.2</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="menu">Link2
        <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li>Link2.1</li>
          <li>Link2.2</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="menu">Link3</li>
      <li class="menu">Link4</li>
      <li class="menu">Link5</li>
    </ul>
```

Remove the spaces. if you are refering to li with class .menu it should be with no space. if you have space space it will look for child